# Can we set custom expire time to Azure AD Authentication In MVC Web Application

Tags: azure, authentication, model-view-controller

I have an MVC application in which I want to implement a secondary authentication where I just have to see if user is authenticated or not and expire credentials in 30 seconds. So that user will be again authenticated before performing specific action in application. I don't want to keep logged in information in browser cookies and expire in seconds after user put its credentials.

How can I achieve it?

[Followed these steps to implement azure authentication](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-ad-authentication-for-mvc-web-application/)

Comment: You can modify your authentication time on azure portal.

Comment: How about setting expiresUtc and IsPersistent flag in Authentication properties? Will it have any effect on timeout of authentication?

Comment: It will persist your token life time as authentication duration as well.

Comment: What if I set UseTokenLifetime = false in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions? Is there any other way to just authenticate and not persist the authentication? I want to authenticate every time any specific action performed in my app.